# Spring MVC: Request Mapping for JSONObject in Request body

Tags: java, spring, rest

```
import org.json.JSONObject;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")

        public @ResponseBody void uploadMultipleFileHandler(@RequestBody JSONObject validationData,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            System.out.println(validationData);
    }
```

I am unable to map this request form Postman. Its giving me error : `description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

But if I change the JSONObject to String then its working form POSTMAN.

Comment: are you using any json serialization library ?

Comment: Im using org.json

Comment: can you please share the input what you are sending from UI

Comment: https://ibb.co/hC6JJ5

Comment: or you can try storing it into string then convert into JSONObject or other way you  can create a model object based on your payload

Comment: I am able to get it in org.simple.json.JSOnObject  but it is removing null values form data. I want to preserve it. Any thought on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that ?
Use `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> validationData` instead of @RequestBody JSONObject validationData.
Hope this will help you.

```
    public void getValues(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> validationData, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
         System.out.println(pvmValues.get("key"));
     }
```

Comment: No.. its not working.I am able to get it in org.simple.json.JSOnObject but it is removing null values form data. I want to preserve it. Any thought on that ?